# What's the difference between click and submit in Mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I am trying to log in to Facebook using [Mechanize](https://pypi.org/project/mechanize/).

I have written these two different scripts to log in:

## Script 1

```
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

userName = 'My EmailID'
password = 'My Password'
response = br.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
if response.code is 200:
    loginForm = br.forms()[0]
    loginForm.set_value(userName, type='email')
    loginForm.set_value(password, type="password")
    response = loginForm.click(label='Log In')
```

## Script 2

```
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

userName = 'My EmailID'
password = 'My Password'
response = br.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
if response.code is 200:
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.set_value(userName, type='email')
    br.set_value(password, type="password")
    response = br.submit()
```

The second script logged me on to Facebook, but not the first way.

Even though I click on correct submit button in the first script, why didn't it work?

[image: HTML FORM]

Comment: You click a widget (button, text box etc..) and submit a form. perhaps the "button" is hidden or there is a conflict when trying to click on an object with type=submit?

Comment: I have even tried with loginForm.click(label='Log In') to ensure if i am clicking login button. but it didn't logged me in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**
Sorry for the late reply.
Here is the way if you want to use click:

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

userName = ''
password = ''
response = br.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
if response.code is 200:
    loginForm = br.forms()[0]
    loginForm.set_value(userName, type='email')
    loginForm.set_value(password, type="password")

    br.select_form(nr=0)
    req = br.click(label='Log In')
    response = br.open(req)
```

Comment: I am trying to click a button using the FORM instance i,e is login form so i gave loginForm.click(label='Log In')